# ProcID lineage identification

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I am working with SQL Server 2008 and need for stored proc B to be able to give (whether that means storeor print etc...) the name/id of stored proc A which called it. I.e. I would like to find the value of the parent of @@ProcID.

I have seen the question has been asked but not given a satisfactory answer (from Microsoft or any online community) so I thought there would be a clevr solution using sp_who in combination with master..sysprocesses but I haven't come up with one.

Comment: IIRC, there's a way to determine the outermost stored proc called by a connection (so if the connection executed `A,` which in turn executed `B`, you could find `A`), but no way to find intermediaries (so if the connection executes `A`, which executes `C`, which executes `B`, there's no way I know of to find out about `C`).

Comment: What would be the method for doing this? Generally, the process will not be called at the end of a chain it will just be the B executed by A/

Comment: towards the end of the article @CResults links to, there's mention of using `DBCC INPUTBUFFER` to see what command was actually sent by the connection.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there is a way to do this in SQL Server. However, you could have a look at this solution (and the feature request he references)

http://www.thecodepage.com/post/TIP-A-Call-Stack-in-SQL-Server.aspx

Alternatively, why not just make it a requirement that the calling SP passes it's name as one of the parameters. If both SPs are under your ownership this would probably be the easiest (and quickest, most efficient) solution

Comment: Thank you very much for the info. I have written the stored proc to require a parameter. I was hoping there would be a way to identify the procedure that called it without requiring the procid to be passed in this way but as you have shown this seems to be difficult/impossible to do. I would vote you up but I don't have 15 reputation yet :-)